# React Synthetic Events vs Native Javascript Events?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, debugging, events

I have a hard time understanding react synthetic events.

The way I debug with native javascript events is something like this

```
window.addEventListener('mousemove',
  function(event){
    console.log(event);
})
```

If I move my mouse, and check the console, I can see the events properties such as `target` and other useful properties such as `innerHTML`, `nextElementSibling`, `lastChild` etc.

[image]

I have a simple react app below. Its an input field with a submit button. If something is entered in the input when submitted, an alert pops up. Otherwise nothing

```js
// React Synthetic Events
class AddOption extends React.Component {
  handleAddOption(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(e);
    const option = e.target.elements.option.value; // < HOW WOULD I FIND THIS IN THE DEBUGGER?
    if (option){
      alert("something was entered in");
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
          <input type="text" name="option" />
          <button>React Submit</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    )
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<AddOption />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="app"><!-- reactapp -->
```

What I don't get is if I inspect the page it doesn't give that useful information like I get with native events.

The issue is I referenced in my reactapp (following a tutorial) to use `e.target.element.options.value`. I have no idea how someone would find that out in the debugger. I don't see a reference to anything dubbed `element` in any of the long nested chain of prototype properties under synthetic event's `target`. I tried  <kbd>CTRL+F</kbd> but I don't think chrome supports searching nested prototypes

Am I not understanding something about things happening in the virtual DOM / react in general?

[image]

Comment: My guess is that you're trying to access a released SyntheticEvent. Try calling `e.persist()` to keep the event around, so that you can see its properties in DevTools

Comment: it worked :) . what does it do exactly relative to reacts virtual dom? If you put an answer I'll upvote and mark it as a solution

Comment: It's for performance reasons. There is only ever one `SyntheticEvent` as it's pooled and reused (thats why when you log it in DevTools and then try to view its properties asynchronously, you get null).

Comment: does vueJS also use `syntheticEvents` as well? Is there a simple js snippet/library out there demonstrating how synthetic events are made?

Comment: You can go through the React source. From what I gather, it's just a wrapper around W3C's actual event spec with some added functionality for performance.

Answer (score 2):

per li357 comment, adding `e.persist()` right before the `console.log(e)` statement in original post shows this in the debugger. You can see the native javascript event's properties include `target`, `element` and the defined `option` from react

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `e.nativeEvent` to get access to the native event and from there on to the `elements.option.value` property:

```
// React Synthetic Events
class AddOption extends React.Component {
    handleAddOption(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log(e);

      const option = e.target.elements.option.value; // < HOW WOULD I FIND THIS IN THE DEBUGGER?
      // > YOU CAN USE e.nativeEvent TO GET ACCESS TO THE NATIVE EVENT:
      console.log(e.nativeEvent);
      console.log(e.nativeEvent.target.elements.option.value); // < HERE IS YOUR VALUE

      if (option){
        alert("something was entered in");
      }
    }
    render() {
      return (
        <div>
          <form onSubmit={this.handleAddOption}>
            <input type="text" name="option" defaultValue={"Toy"}/>
            <button>React Submit</button>
          </form>
        </div>
      )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<AddOption />, document.getElementById('root'));
```